How to match all routes in Flask?
I want to match all routes and handle all received HTTP requests in Flask. The code is as follows:
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<path:full_path>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'POST'])
def catch_all(full_path):
    print(request.url)
    return request.url

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8080, host='0.0.0.0', ssl_context='adhoc', debug=True)

The above code works well except the case that the "static" is in the path. For example, if the url is https://127.0.0.1:8080/static/index.html, then the above code doesn't work. How to fix this problem?
I try to solve this problem by modifying the code as
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

It still doesn't work.

What exactly is not working? Could you provide more detailed description of what you're trying to achieve, what request you send and what error you get?

When I type "https://127.0.0.1:8080/static/index.html", the response is "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." This message means this URL is not matched.

The problem you are facing is caused by the way Flask handles static files. By default, all static files are located under the /static/* path which conflicts with the path you are trying to use.
Flask has no setting to completely disable static file routing, so you essentially have 2 options:

Change the path that you currently use

Change the static path (just like you tried) using app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/other_static_path"), but keep in mind that this new path just replaces the static url path and now blocks /other_static_path/*. This fix should only be used temporary until Flask officially implements a way to disable static file serving



The way you tried to fix the issue just changed the static path to /* which essentially makes Flask always send a static file (or the error you encountered if the file doesn't exist).
Keep in mind that the / path is not covered by either approach and needs to be implemented manually:
@app.route('/')
def root():
  return catch_all('/')


If you do not want flask to match static paths then simply set static_folder=None when creating your app.
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)

